# Data Centers vs Internet Data Centers (IDCs)

Tags: data-center

Are the terms data center and Internet Data Centers (IDCs) same or 2 different things. In some sources they mention that they are pretty much the same thing. But in some other sources they are mentioned as they are very similar but not exactly the same thing.

Which one is correct? Are they same or 2 different things. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

These terms aren't formally defined so they can be used as people like. There's no right or wrong, and their meaning may depend on the context and the person using them.

Comment: But, is there any difference, I mean there must be some reason to have 2 names, right?

Comment: Since there is no formal definition, you should ask the person using those terms that. We can only guess what they mean.